# spring and iBatis integration AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver$1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ibatis

I am new to spring and iBatis.I am trying to integrate both and i have placed all the needed jars.But still it is throwing the following exception.
I think i miised a corresponding jar.But i am unable to figure it.Can any one please help me regarding this.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver$1
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver$1
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.findBestExceptionHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:131)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:987)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:811)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver$1
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.findBestExceptionHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:131)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:987)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:811)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Thanks in advance.
Janardhan.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using spring-3.0 (as this class doesn't exist in older versions), so the missing class is in `spring-webmvc-3.x.x.jar`, e.g.:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE/

Comment: i placed spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE-sources jar.But still same problem.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you think is in the *-sources.jar? It contains the sources not the classes. And you need to take exactly the same version of spring-webmvc as of the rest of your spring jars, so if you really use spring 3.0.5, then take "spring-webmvc-3.0.5.jar (without "sources").